# How can i show the results which as multiple values in the column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

## Table 1

```
Code Division IsActive Company
A     A         1       Test1
B     B         1       Test1
C     C         1       Test1
D     D         1       Test2
E     E         1       Test2
F     F         1       Test2
```

### Trascation Table2

```
 Code Division 
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D
    5   A,B
    6   E,f
    7   E
    8   F
```

`Select * from table2 where (Select code from table1 where company = 'Test1')` -- with this query i cant get the columns (5(A,B)) and 6(E,F))

So i tweaked the query to :

```
Select 
  * 
from table2 
where 
 (Select 
    code 
  from table1 
  where 
    contains(code, 'A') 
    or 
    contains(code, 'B')
 )
```

I dont want to hard code the values(Divisions) how can i pass through Parameter!!

Comment: The problem isn't your query, it's your data. Don't store delimited data in your table. Are you open/able to fix your design?

Comment: Your sample queries are syntactically incorrect (at least for SQL Server).  They will only return an error, because scalar subqueries are not the same as boolean expressions.

Comment: I Have updated the query with more specific information, hope that's clear to answer!!

Comment: Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my stored procedure and that resolved my issue

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_division] division ON folder.divisions like concat ('%', division.code , '%')
    WHERE folder.[StatusCode] > 0 AND viewFolderItem.[StatusCode] > 0 And division.company = 'Test1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with STRING_SPLIT from SQL Server 2016:

```
    declare @table1 table (Code char(2), Division char(2), IsActive bit, Company nvarchar(100))
    insert into @table1 values
      ('A', 'A', 1, 'Test1')
    , ('B', 'B', 1, 'Test1')
    , ('C', 'C', 1, 'Test1')
    , ('D', 'D', 1, 'Test2')
    , ('E', 'E', 1, 'Test2')
    , ('F', 'F', 1, 'Test2')

    declare @table2 table (Code char(2), Division varchar(100))
    insert into @table2 values
      (1, 'A')
    , (2, 'B')
    , (3, 'C')
    , (4, 'D')
    , (5, 'A,B')
    , (6, 'E,f')
    , (7, 'E')
    , (8, 'F')

    SELECT distinct t2.*
    FROM @table2 t2
    cross apply string_split(t2.Division, ',')
    inner join @table1 t1 on  t1.Division = [value]
    where t1.Company = 'Test1'

SELECT t1.*, t2.*, [value] as Table2Division
FROM @table2 t2
cross apply string_split(t2.Division, ',')
inner join @table1 t1 on  t1.Division = [value]
```

Comment: My last query is part of a stored procedure where i have to pass the company from table1 to fetch the values from table2 based on division(Division is common column in both tables), In table2 we have columns with value A,B where i cant get in result set. How can i get them as well without hardcoding the division.

Comment: @JP. I am not sure I understood, but I have supplied all columns without clause at the end in the answer above.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i have updated the initial query with more information, hope that helps to answer my question!! thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: string_split is not compatible! any other solution!!